# Problema con la carga de un ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

**Buenas, hice esta pregunta anteriormente y se solucionó pero hoy me topo con el mismo dilema y no estaría entendiendo porque me funciona en un `ComboBox` y en otro no. Verán, esta es la **clase:**

```
class TipoPlan
{
    public int tipoPlan { get; set; }

    public TipoPlan() { }

    public TipoPlan(int tipoPlan)
    {
        this.tipoPlan = tipoPlan;
    }

    public string toString()
    {
        return tipoPlan.ToString();
    }
}
```

Esta es la conexión que hago:

```
    public List<TipoPlan> cantidadCuotas(string valor)
    {
        List<TipoPlan> salida = new List<TipoPlan>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(BD))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT ancantcuoplan " +
                "FROM v_solicitudweb " +
                "WHERE asesor = @ase " +
                "GROUP BY ancantcuoplan";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ase", valor);
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        int cantCuotas= Convert.ToInt32(dr["ancantcuoplan"]?.ToString());
                        TipoPlan tp = new TipoPlan(cantCuotas);
                        salida.Add(tp);
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    return salida;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Cuando depuro, me trae el valor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, en la siguiente línea me imprime `ProvidusApp.Clases.TipoPlan`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como estoy cargando el valor:

```
    private void llenarCuotas()
    {
        string valorAsesor = cmbAsesor.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if(valorAsesor != "")
        {
            ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
            cmbTipoPlan.ValueMember = "ancantcuoplan";
            cmbTipoPlan.DisplayMember = "ancantcuoplan";
            cmbTipoPlan.DataSource = conexionSQL.cantidadCuotas(valorAsesor);
        }
    }
```

Y lo aplico en el evento:

```
    private void cmbAsesor_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        llenarCuotas();
    }
```

Pero, en el `ComboBox` se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me podría explicar en dónde o cómo es que me estoy equivocando?

Comment: SAlida es una lista de tipoplan.. vos le decis al combo, que por cada objeto, use la propiedad ancantcuoplan para llenarse.. yo no veo esa propiedad en tipoplan...  y tipoplan toString, es simplemente el nombre de la clase....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es el siguiente: el método por default de todo `object` es `ToString` (con mayúscula) y tú estás declarando un método `toString` (con minúscula).

Para sobreescribir el método, necesitas usar la palabra clave `override`:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return tipoPlan.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Es porque luego voy a ir añadiendo más variables, pero gracias, funcionó

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo ¡Me alegra que funcionara! Modifiqué el texto para ir directo al grano, sin mencionar lo de la clase.